# Auth JWT in decorator in NESTJS

Tags: jwt, nestjs

how can i decode jwt cookies in a decorator in nestjs? i can't  use "private readonly jwtService: JwtService" in decorator, i use jwt-decode but it still work while jwt is out of date

Comment: Why not have a guard decode and validate the JWT, then set the payload to a property on the `req`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel because my teacher require get current user by decorator

Comment: That's still doable. You use a guard to decode it using the `JwtService` then use a decorator to get the information off the `req` object and into the controller

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should have to use AuthGuard to decode the JwtToken

Please refer below document from NestJs
https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) in that case.

```
//user.decorator.ts
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator((data: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return request.user;
});
```

Now we can use this User decorator in controllers

```
//user.controller.ts
import { User } from './user.decorator';

@Get()
async getUser(@User() user) {
  //console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: What about the return type? Is there a way to make it not return `any`?

Comment: @EnriqueDev In this case, you can remove the data parameter as we are not passing anything in the @User() decorator. But if you pass something like @User('userId') then you can add the return type as 'string'. But if you pass a parameter then you will have access to that particular field of User object only.

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/rasoolkhan16/f609fb66bb82fcdaaee9e6126445ad09

Comment: I get your point, but I was wondering if there was a way to make the decorator `infer` the return type automatically.