# Get user data in RoleGuard with passport JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, nestjs, passport-jwt

I've managed to get JWT authentication in my nestJS application.
Now I want to implement the role guard and have therefore to check the role of the authenticated user.
Therefore, I thought of requesting the respective user role from the database. But this call is async and this is not doable within the guard.

My question is:
How can I get the user role information within the Guard?
I could put the information in the JWT token, but this seems not right to me, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, [Implementing Passport JWT](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt) you can put your findUser in the validate function that is async. And then create a decorator to return the user [Auth JWT in decorator in NESTJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69453660/auth-jwt-in-decorator-in-nestjs)

So you need to do some things like this

```js
//jwt.strategy.ts
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    // Your JWT payload
    // Insert here the findOne from you're BDD
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username };
  }
}
```

And then

```js
//user.decorator.ts
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator((data: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return request.user;
});
```

And in your controller juste use

```js
//user.controller.ts
import { User } from './user.decorator';

@Get()
async getUser(@User() user) {
  //console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: Ah, so I fetch the additional user data in the async JWT-guard validate function before passing them to the role-guard. 

Nice! Thank you!